# Is it possible to add text with angle brackets at the front and end without it being detected as an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add text to my site that includes angle brackets (for example: "<a_username>"), but it keeps getting recognized as an element.

Is there anyway to prevent that?

In my code, I'm trying to write a `<p>` that says:

```
<p><span><server> Welcome.</span></p>
```

but obviously, `<server>` is being detected as an element.

Comment: Try adding &lt; and &gt; in place of the brackets

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you're trying to add it. I have a feeling you're using `innerHTML` when `textContent` would be more appropriate

Comment: @jsejcksn that would entirely depend on OP's ability to alter the source string